# Excel Pivot table count number of orders from a customer per year

Tags: excel, count, pivot, pivot-table, average

Excel

I'm creating a pivot table and need a column to describe 'average number of orders' made by customers each year.

I have:

- Order date
- Customer ID
- Year

I'm thinking calculated feild, and using COUNT(Order date) to determine number of orders. But I need to be able to use that to get the average number of orders for each customer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Date set example:

```
Customer ID Order date
Xh015046    12/04/2016
X7615777    03/06/2016
X10062024   20/04/2017
X7615777    25/06/2016
X7615777    05/01/2017
Xh015046    15/04/2017
X10062024   09/07/2018
X7615777    10/07/2018
Xh015046    11/07/2018
X10062024   12/07/2018
```

Pivot table I want:

```
Year    Average Number of orders per customer
2016    1.5
2017    1
2018    1.333333333
```

Comment: You mean their average yearly order? So if Customer A ordered 20 times in 2020 and 10 times in 2021 then you would expect to see 15 (=(20+10)/2) as their result?

Comment: And what if a customer has a year in which they order nothing? Should that be included or excluded from their average? For example, if Customer A ordered 0 times in 2019, 20 times in 2020 and 10 times in 2021 then you would expect to see 15 (=(20+10)/2) as their result, or 10 (=(0+20+10)/3)?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it, I need a way to calculate average yearly order in a pivot table

Comment: It shouldn't matter as I am separating it by year with a 'year' value in the 'rows' section of the pivot. But it would be the latter i.e. 10 (=(0+20+10)/3)

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you have year in the rows areas, won't the result for their average yearly order just be the same as their total orders in that year?

Comment: Maybe you should include a small sample dataset together with your expected results.

Comment: I've added a small dataset and expected pivot table format for some clarity

Comment: Ah, I see. The results are to be calculated across all customers. Thanks, understood now.

Comment: Ok, agree with your totals for 2017 and 2018, but not sure how you get 1.5 for 2016? Xh015046 has 1 order in that year, X7615777 has 2 and X10062024 has 0, so that's (1+2+0)/3=1. You said previously that zero orders count, but here you seem to be excluding X10062024's figure from your calculation.

Comment: You're right in my haste I did do that, my apologies

Comment: Do you have a version of Excel with Power Pivot?

Comment: Just checked and it seems I do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Data Model (Power Pivot), create a new measure:

```
AverageOrders :=
VAR MyTable =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1,
        [Customer ID],
        "Order Count", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Table1 ) )
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX ( MyTable, [Order Count] )
```

Amend the table (Table1) and column (Customer ID) names in the above as required.

Then create a Pivot Table within the worksheet with *Year* in the Rows section and the above measure *AverageOrders* in the Values section.

Comment: It says I need to start it with an =, but when I put one I get the following error:


The expression is not valid or appears to be incomplete. Please review and correct the expression.
The syntax for ':' is incorrect. (DAX(
AverageOrders :=
VAR Mytable =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1,
        [Customer_id],
        "Order Count", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Table1 ) )
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX ( table1, [Order Count] )
)).

Comment: Did you put it in the Calculation Area? That's where any measures should be stored within the Power Pivot window.

Comment: Yeah I'm in the calculations >Measures, area of Power pivot

Comment: Ah, you've done it that way. Then simply put AverageOrders as the Measure name then in the Formula box put what I posted but starting with the = sign, i.e. excluding "AverageOrders :"

Comment: I've got to making the pivot table but it says 'Column 'Order count' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression'

Comment: When and where does it give you that message?

Comment: Ah wait. Just noticed you've replaced "MyTable" with "table1" (after the AVERAGEX) in your version of the formula I posted. That needs to stay as "MyTable"; only change "Table1" to match the name of your actual table.

Comment: Thank you, you are incredible!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad we got there in the end!